# Is there a way to use a boilerplate for CSS?

Tags: magento2, css, design, less

I have to redesign an existing M2-Shop with a given style guide.
That guide defines structures for headlines, sub-lines, product etc. like a style guide does.

My problem is that there is no given structure in the less structure to change that easily.

Is that even possible to have a let's say boilerplate for CSS?

The styles are spread all over the less files. To say a headline H1 has to have a font size with 24px and a red text color and maybe a given line height that modifications I have also to change in every less file e.g. `cms.less`, `product.less`, `product-list.less` and so on.

Is there a way to simplify that?

Answer (score 0):

**Load your css at last after all the css and less files initiated it will automatically override the style**

**layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="css/newtheme.css" />
        </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the easiest way to add your own `.less` file and in this file, you can override all the styles with your styles, from all over the page. You can write the code in less or in css - both will work. Place it in `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/web/css/source/_extend.less`. Just an example from my code:

```
@whiteColor: #fff;
@redColor: #f00;

.red-buttons {
  color: @whiteColor;
  background-color: @redColor;
  border: 0; 
}
```